# Ow can a random variable can define a measure on $(\Omega , \mathcal F)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a measure space. I know that a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ define a measure $\nu$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ by $$\nu(A)=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}.$$ This is called the pushforward measure.

But it's written in my lecture that it also define a measure on $\Omega $. How is this possible ? What is the measure induced by $X$ on $\Omega $ ? Is is the pullback measure ?

Comment: See, e.g., [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122704/pullback-measures)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: It does as far as you consider the $\sigma -$algebra $\sigma (X)$ on $\Omega $.